# How can I set RenderingHints globally?

Tags: java, graphics, rendering

For a Java application, can I set the RenderingHints on a global basis? Currently, I've defined these in the paintComponent method as shown below. I would prefer, however, to set them once when the application starts and have them persist throughout the session.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
super.paintComponent(g);

Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [system propert](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html#aaFonts)y for that.

Comment: That handles KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, but what about KEY_ANTIALIASING?

Comment: Looks like this will handle it for the text. However, as mmyers pointed out I've not seen an option for KEY_ANTIALIASING. 

System.setProperty("swing.aatext","true");

Comment: The system property is ignored by the Motif look-and-feel ☹